# How to design a circuit

Tags: circuit-design

I'm recent graduate from top 20 school with bachelors in Electrical Engineering with a decent GPA and fairly good theoretical background. In college I pretty much did what I was told to do, like build and test circuits that were given to me by the professors. I took some higher level courses where I simulated circuits around some given specs. But in the working world I'm having difficulty determining what components I will need to use( for example adding capacitor or a diode) to design a circuit, or just designing anything simple. I guess I have very little ability to think practically. What steps do you think I can take now to become better at thinking practically and become better Electrical engineer? What steps did you take to develop that skill?

Comment: Sorry, this question isn't really a good fit for the SE format. But ... you know ... think of some circuit you'd like to design, then see if you can figure out a way to design it...

Comment: You're answering your own question – *In college I pretty much did what I was told to do*, do not do that exclusively. Gather experience by reading books of your own choice, solving your design problems on your own. Get away from the "I want to be taught" idea. Use the "I want to learn this *my way*". It's not too late, learn from existing circuits, understand them. Keep reading until you understand them. ask your fellow engineers if reading a lot doesn't suffice.

Comment: Try. Make mistakes.

Comment: I'm fairly sure we all fried a few dollars worth of components to get here.

Comment: I really want to emphasize @MarcusMüller s point. Try this stuff on your own figure out what works and doesn't work. Find something you want to build and then *build it*. If you break something or it doesn't work, so what?! You ruined $1.00 worth of components? so have all of us!

Comment: **_Study the work of others_**!

Comment: As @jonk says, and there are many questions here where the reasons for picking a particular part are carefully and sometimes even patiently explained and you can learn from those. It will help too to look at real (especially commercial) designs that are far more complex than shown here and see what elements and principles you can recognize.

Comment: I feel I should share with you a story from my recent college days on the dangers of doing exactly what you're told. We once had a lab where we were doing some transistor sweeps from 0-200mA on a computerised test jig. Everything worked fine until 40mA where the test jig (everyone's test jig) went nuts and crashed. The staff would say "ah, you must have a blown transistor", all of us? I think not. I got fed up and used the old fashioned method of a bench power supply and a multimeter. We were the only group that finished (turns out the test jigs were limited to 40mA! - *and no-one knew*)

Answer (score 4):

I would say design as much as you can. I liked electrical engineering as a hobby. While I was in school I would also design PCB's and have a few projects on the side in my spare time. I did this to start a company, none of the projects ever got to that level, but I gained some valuable skills that made it easy for me to get a great job.

Another way I gained skills is through student projects. I did the equivalent of 5 projects that would have qualified for a senior design project.

You need to start looking at job postings, and look at the jobs you'd want to have and then look at the requirements. Then come up with a project that you need to learn X skill or X tool. Your employers will thank you for having those skills.

If you want a DSP job, then buy a DSP board and start working through tutorials, if you want an analog engineering job then build your own op-amp out of discreets. There is sooo soo much information out there, there are videos and tutorials on many things.

1. Learn what resources you need
2. Learn how to find the resource and interpolate between different resources
   (do I need a book? a web tutorial\resource? a research paper?)
3. Build your thing.

Answer (score 2):

Read "The Art of Electronics" by Horowitz and Hill.  Think about functions.  Look at application notes, especially analog designs.  Read hobby and Ham magazines.  Build something and fiddle with it.  Think of something you want to do, and design it.  Build it.  Figure out why it doesn't work. Get a cheap DVM.  eBay is a good source for component assortments. Start simple.

Comment: +1 for H&H. Budget for an inexpensive digital oscilloscope as one of your first test equipment purchases.

Comment: Build a logarithmic-sweep WeinBridge audio oscillator, 10Hz to 10,000Hz. With controlled output amplitude. You'll get log/antilog, oscillators, bridges, amplitude, poor-tracking-RCs to correct, at least 2 control loops. And you may as well build +-15 volt power supplies. Regulated with discrete circuits.